# React Router: this.props.location.state is null

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router` `2.4.0` and I am trying to pass in some state to my route on a click event. It passes in `pathname` and `query` correctly but `state` is `null`.

Below is my handler function

```
clickHandler: function() {
    var navigate = { pathname: '/view/report',
                     query: { filter: "filter-val"}, 
                     state: {"field": this.state.field} 
                   }
    this.props.router.push(navigate);
```

In my component that renders the route, inside `getInitialState` I am trying to access the state but it comes up as `null`.

I logged the `this.state.field` and it is present after the button press but before routing. I also logged `this.props.location` inside the`getInitialState` of the routed component and it has non-null values for things like `query`, `pathname`, etc. but `state`  (`this.props.location.state` to be specific) shows up as `null`.

Is there something special I need to do to set an object inside `state` of the router's location?

Comment: v2.4.0 is an old version. While I'm not aware of any reason why this would be causing your error, it might help to try upgrade to v3 (just v2 with v1's deprecated code removed). Assuming that doesn't actually fix your issue, try inserting a log of the received location before this line https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.4.1/modules/createTransitionManager.js#L264. That will be the `location` that is received from `history`. If that does not contain the `state`, then the issue might be with the `history` module.

Comment: @PaulS Thanks! Upgrading to 3.0.0 worked. Do you mind posting this as the answer and I will accept it? I was very nervous upgrading it because this is not my code and I was not sure if anything will break. So far it seems to be ok.

Comment: I'm not sure why that fixed it, but I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v2.4.0 is an old version. While I'm not aware of any reason why this would be causing your error, it might help to try upgrade to v3 (just v2 with v1's deprecated code removed).